# Where is the function series $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}$ differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, derivatives

I was asked to analyze the convergence, continuity and differentiability intervals of the next function series:

> $f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}$

I already know that this series converge only for $x\geq0$ and that it is continuous in each of these points because of the Weierstrass M-test. However, I can't figure out how to analyze the differentiablity, so I'd appreciate some hints, or some sources regarding these kind of exercises. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $i=n$? You use both in your answer, most likely a mistake.

Comment: @Cataline Certainly. Thanks, I just fixed it.

Comment: You have to study the **uniform** convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n'(x)$ (note the derivative sign), where $f_n(x) = e^{-nx}/(n^2+1)$.

Comment: Recall that if the $f_n$ are differentiable with $f_n\to f$ uniformly, then $f_n' \to f'$ (in particular, $f'$ exists) with some mild additional assumptions.

Answer (score 2):

*I am not sure that this is an answer to the question (but it is too long for a comment); so, please, forgive me if I am off-topic.*

The problem can be simplified writing first $$\frac 1{n^2+1}=\frac{i}{2 (n+i)}-\frac{i}{2 (n-i)}$$ Then $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{-nx}}{n+i}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1-i\right) e^{-x} \, _2F_1\left(1,1+i;2+i;e^{-x}\right)-i$$ $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{-nx}}{n-i}=\frac{1}{2}\left(1+i\right) e^{-x} \, _2F_1\left(1,1-i;2-i;e^{-x}\right)+i$$ from which $$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{e^{-nx}}{n^2+1}=\frac{1}{2} \big(\, _2F_1\left(-i,1;1-i;e^{-x}\right)+\,
   _2F_1\left(i,1;1+i;e^{-x}\right)\big)$$ where appear the [hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) which have the required properties for the problem.